# What is the proper way of building a static binary with openssl?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have the following make file:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
REST_LIBS = -lssl -lcrypto -lboost_system -lcpprest

all: main

main: static_pack
    g++ -std=c++14 -D DEBUG -Wfatal-errors -static -pthread -I$(basepath)/vendors/cpp-jwt/include -I$(basepath)/vendors/json/include \
    -DTS=\"/ctts.json\" \
    -DCS_PATH=\"/bin\" \
    -DCTFS_ENC=\"/ctfs.enc\" \
    -DUNTAR_PATH=\"/\" \
    -DCLUSTER_PATH=\"/.clusters\" \
     -o run main.cpp \
    libmain.a && \
    rm -rf debpkg/cs/usr/bin/cs debpkg/cs.deb && \
    cp run debpkg/cs/usr/bin/cs && \
    dpkg-deb -b debpkg/cs && \
    mv debpkg/cs.deb .

static_pack: rest.o aes.o random.o
    ar rcs libmain.a random.o aes/aes.o rest/rest.o

rest.o:
    g++ -std=c++14 -Wfatal-errors -c $(REST_LIBS) -o rest/rest.o rest/rest.cpp 


aes.o: random.o
    g++ -std=c++14 -D DEBUG -Wfatal-errors -c -lcrypto -o aes/aes.o random.o aes/aes.cpp

random.o:
    g++ -std=c++14 -Wfatal-errors -c -o random.o random.cpp
```

If I compile this to be dynamically linked I have no problems. However, when I try static compilation I get tons of errors such as:

```
aes.cpp:(.text+0x706): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
aes.cpp:(.text+0x732): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
aes.cpp:(.text+0x763): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl'
aes.cpp:(.text+0x792): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
aes.cpp:(.text+0x7a1): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
```

Essentially none of the symbols are being found. I'm not sure what I need to do now. I've tried build my object files as static to but that fails. I've looked into linking order, but that seems right.

My question boils down to two things:

1. When static linking other objects, do those objects need to be statically compiled as well + archived?
2. What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: What is the purpose of passing two input files when generating an object file (like you do for `aes.o`)?

Comment: As for your problem, where are the missing functions supposed to be? Are you missing an object or source file? Are you perhaps missing linking with a library?

Comment: I build my applications in a modular way. I can unit test seperate modules like random.o which I've ommited from the SO question. Build all of my unit tests around .o files I then later link those files together to build the application.

If I wanted to turn those files into seperate lib files, that would be easy to.

Comment: All of the missing functions are already in the .so libs installed on the system. I've double checked and my libs also have .a components to them as well so it should be able to retrieve my symbols... libssl.a and libcrypto.a are on the system in the lib path.

Comment: Why the down vote. Unless you're offering an obvious answer to the question or a critique on how to improve, you should not be allowed to down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `REST_LIBS` for your `rest.o` rule, as it only compiles a source file. You need to pass those libraries to g++ in `main` rule - as part of it, g++ will call linker.

Comment: Thanks I was always unsure about that piece in my make file

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently linking happens in the opposite order than I thought... and I think it's possible I might have not been linking either originally as a fufu mistake.

```
REST_LIBS = -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lcpprest -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
# /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a

all: main

main: static_pack
    g++ -std=c++14 -D DEBUG -Wfatal-errors -I$(basepath)/vendors/cpp-jwt/include -I$(basepath)/vendors/json/include \
    -DTS=\"/ctts.json\" \
    -DCS_PATH=\"/bin\" \
    -DCTFS_ENC=\"/ctfs.enc\" \
    -DUNTAR_PATH=\"/\" \
    -DCLUSTER_PATH=\"/.clusters\" \
     -o run main.cpp \
    libmain.a $(REST_LIBS) -pthread  && \
    rm -rf debpkg/cs/usr/bin/cs debpkg/cs.deb && \
    cp run debpkg/cs/usr/bin/cs && \
    dpkg-deb -b debpkg/cs && \
    mv debpkg/cs.deb .
```